# Template constructor is not inherited by derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

For some reason, Clang does not accept the following seemingly correct code, while GCC does:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T val;
};


template <typename T>
struct Base {
    template <typename U> requires std::is_same_v<U, Wrapper<T>>
    Base(U&&) { puts("Base constructor called"); }
};


template <typename T>
struct S : Base<T> {
    using B = Base<T>;

    using B::B;

    template <typename U> requires std::is_constructible_v<T, U>
    S(U&& v)
        : B( Wrapper<T>{ T(v) } ) { puts("S constructor called"); }
};


int main()
{
    // calls S constructor as expected
    S<int> a(10);

    // with GCC, calls Base constructor as expected,
    // Clang fails to compile this
    S<int> b(Wrapper<int>{1});
}
```

This code uses C++20 concepts syntax, but the outcome is the same if I use SFINAE, and I tried different forms of sfinae (both `typename = std::enable_if_t<...>` and `std::enable_if_t<..., bool> = true` as a last template parameter) the outcome is same.

Interestingly, when I remove forwarding reference (`&&`) from either `Base` constructor parameter or `S` (derived class) constructor parameter, the code compiles with Clang too. Or similarly if I add argument with default value to either constructor the issue goes away.
It looks like Clang sees those two constructors as having same "signature" and discards the one from the base class, here's excerpt from cppreference about Using-declaration and inheriting constructors:

```
As with using-declarations for any other non-static member functions,
if an inherited constructor matches the signature of one of the
constructors of Derived, it is hidden from lookup by the version
found in Derived.
```

However if I take the base class constructor and move it to the derived class it compiles, meaning they don't match, otherwise I'd get a redeclaration error.
Is this a bug in Clang or am I misunderstanding something?

The error from clang is as follows:

```
foobar.cpp:37:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'S<int>'
    S<int> b(Wrapper<int>{1});
           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foobar.cpp:19:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known con
version from 'Wrapper<int>' to 'const S<int>' for 1st argument
struct S : Base<T> {
       ^
foobar.cpp:19:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known con
version from 'Wrapper<int>' to 'S<int>' for 1st argument
struct S : Base<T> {
       ^
foobar.cpp:25:5: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with U = Wrapper<int>]
    S(U&& v)
    ^
foobar.cpp:24:36: note: because 'std::is_constructible_v<int, Wrapper<int> >' evaluated to false
    template <typename U> requires std::is_constructible_v<T, U>
                                   ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Clang 16.0.0 and trunk accept it: https://godbolt.org/z/r6v3KxdPs. Possibly a recently patched bug?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Interesting, I'm on Clang 15.0.7 and I thought that's latest version because I'm on a rolling release Linux distro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Clang: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/50886

If anyone stumbles upon this issue too, here's how I worked around it:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T val;
};


template <typename T>
struct Base {
    template <typename U> requires std::is_same_v<U, Wrapper<T>>
    Base(U&&) { puts("Base constructor called"); }
};


template <typename T>
struct S : Base<T> {
    using B = Base<T>;

    using B::B;

    template <typename U> requires std::is_constructible_v<T, U>
    S(U&& v)
        : B( Wrapper<T>{ T(v) } ) { puts("S constructor called"); }
    

#if defined(__clang__) && __clang_major__ < 16
    template <typename U> S(U&& v) : B(std::forward<U>(v)) {}
#endif


};


int main()
{
    // calls S constructor as expected
    S<int> a(10);

    // calls Base constructor as expected
    S<int> b(Wrapper<int>{1});
}
```